# Where can I find WinEdt 9.0 documentation?

Tags: documentation, winedt

I'am making a little tutorial about LaTeX and one of tutorial is about WinEdt. Where can I find WinEdt 9.0 documentation or manual about WinEdt 9.0 complete.  And only found old documentation like this : [old](http://www.itu.dk/stud/projects_f2004/handtracking/program/WinEdt/Doc/HTML/Overview.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the WinEdt documentation can be found simply clicking <kbd>F1</kbd> inside WinEdt 9. It is in `.chm` format.

You can use some tool to convert it to the format you like, if you want.

Note also that it can be opened with SumatraPDF, if you have it installed.

The path to the file is `\WinEdt 9\Doc\Help\WinEdt.chm`

You can also install [HTML Help Workshop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms669985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and decompile the `.chm` file to HTML format.

Comment: @Kalkoeller, sorry out the topic, can I make shortcut from WinEdt ? Let's make shortcut for XeLaTeX like  PDFTeXify (SHIFT+CTRL +P).

Comment: @Hirwanto too long for a comment. Ask a new question indicating the command for which you want the shortcut.